# One-to-One or Many-to-One Association

Tags: database, relationship

Why in the Doctrine Doc first comment is a Many-to-One relationship?

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/working-with-associations.html

```
class User
{
/** Unidirectional - Many-To-One */
    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: Comment::class)]
    private Comment|null $firstComment = null;
...
}

class Comment {
...
}
```

In the schema the example treats this case like a 1:1 relationship and to me it's right:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    firstComment_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Why is it a many to one? I think it's just one to one cause a first comment can be owned by just one user and a user can write just one first comment.